# Search input and button not aligning horizontally properly

Tags: html, css, forms

I am trying to align a form text input and button horizontally on the same line while giving the button a minimum width for a responsive layout. For some reason the minimum width forces the button on to a new line

```
.search-container{
    width:100%;
    border: 1px solid #000;
    display:block;
 }
.search-text-container {
    width:90%;
    display:inline-block;
}

.search-text-container input {
    width:100%;
    height:30px;
}

.round-icon-container {
    width:10%;
    display:inline-block;
}
.round-icon-button {
    min-width:30px;
    display:block;
    width:30px;
    height:30px;
    line-height:normal;
    border: 2px solid #f5f5f5;
    border-radius: 50%;
    color:#f5f5f5;
    text-align:center;
    text-decoration:none;
    background: #464646;
    box-shadow: 0 0 3px gray;
    font-weight:bold;
}
.round-icon-button:hover {
    background: #262626;
}

<div class="search-container">
    <span class="search-text-container">
        <form action="">
            <input type="text" name="fname" />
        </form>
    </span>
    <span class="round-icon-container">
        <button type="submit" class="round-icon-button">
            <i class="fa fa-search"></i>
        </button>
    </span>
</div>
```

I have a fiddle here of what I am working on http://jsfiddle.net/dnssmw83/19/ any help would be much appreciated

Comment: try this - http://jsfiddle.net/L5Lknas9/

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/lalu050/dnssmw83/23/.. used float:left...

Comment: Thanks Mary and Lal, that's not bad but if you resize the browser window to something narrow the button breaks out of the container. How can that be prevented? Is it possible to make the button dynamic as well do you know?

Comment: so you want it fixed every time..right???

Comment: I want the button to always be on the right of the text input yes, even if the button can shrink responsively that would be good, whatever works

Comment: try my solution with float:left..i think that wont break out of the container.

Comment: I tried yours Lal but it breaks if you resize to around the width of a small smartphone

Comment: Like this? - http://jsfiddle.net/dnssmw83/24/

Comment: but it isnt breaking off [here](http://jsfiddle.net/lalu050/dnssmw83/23/) as you can see..try minimising the browser window..

Comment: Use CSS @media queries for small screen sizes - http://jsfiddle.net/3dn4dyc5/

Comment: Lal in Firefox (latest version) if I resize the browser so that the round-icon-container span is less than the width of the icon (30px) it breaks out of all containers. @Mary I think that is the best solution for this, thanks. If you add your answer to this question I'll tick it if you want. Cheers.

Comment: ...and thanks to everyone else who tried to help with this, much appreciated

Comment: I just realized another way of doing this is to add absolute positioning to the icon and then possibly margin the text input field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could achieve it by using CSS [`@media` queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Media_queries) like this:

**JSFiddle - [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/3dn4dyc5/)**

```
* {
    box-sizing:border-box;
}
@media(max-width:320px) {
    .search-text-container {
        width:70% !important;
    }
    .round-icon-container {
        width:30% !important;
    }
}
.search-container {
    width:100%;
    border: 1px solid #000;
    display:block;
    font-size: 0; /* to remove the space between inline-block elements */
}
.search-container > span {
    font-size: 16px; /* add the font-size to child span elements */
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```